# Why is two way binding between a parent component and a child component bad?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, vue.js

I've been doing development mostly in AngularJS, recently I was looking into Vue.js and reading its guide, on one page it mentions:

> By default, all props form a one-way-down binding between the child property and the parent one: when the parent property updates, it will flow down to the child, but not the other way around. This default is meant to prevent child components from accidentally mutating the parent’s state, which can make your app’s data flow harder to reason about.

This is from https://vuejs.org/guide/components.html#Prop-Binding-Types.

I'm wondering if there are any principles of when to use two way binding, and when not to?

For the case where the child component needs to manage an array variable, it seems that two way binding would make sense.

For example, say I want to make my own Vue.js or AngularJS version of http://selectize.github.io/selectize.js/.

If two way binding is used, I would just pass the parent component's array to my Vue.js or AngularJS selectize component, and let the selectize component manage it.

If two way binding is not used, it seems the alternatives would be:

a. Either the parent component would either have to manually update the array when an item is added/deleted

b. Or the parent would have a function that manually sets the array, this function is then passed to the child component

c. The child component dispatches an event which the parent component listens to, and updates its array

I think these are the alternatives? Both seem more verbose and does not appear to provide much benefit.

This is one example, but I think many components would have this issue, another example would be if I have a product-selector component, it would be convenient to just pass in an array variable into this component, and let the component manage the array to reflect the selected products.

My main questions on this are:

1. Is my idea of the alternatives to two way binding correct?
2. For the mentioned cases, is there an advantage to using one-way-down binding? (I do not see the alternatives providing much advantage to avoid "accidentally mutating the parent’s state")
3. If (1) and (2) are correct, what is an example where one-way-down binding, provides a clear advantage to avoid "accidentally mutating the parent’s state"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"one-way-down binding" is just a principle, similar to OO's Encapsulation, to reduce code complexity.

In my opinion the author didn't mean not to use "two way binding" (actually vuejs support that), just mention you don't abuse it.

In your examples, the product-selector is similar to native input, surely I think you can use two way binding, just like v-model does.